# Cosine distance Weka

Tags: weka

I'm trying to implement cosine distance in Weka, but it's not going so well. It seems like I have to implement a lot to gain a little. I tried following Euclidean distance implementation, but it doesn't implement the interface directly, but extends NormalizableDistance.

Besides that, I tried using K-means++ with my "cosine to be" implementation, but it crashes throwing index out of bounds exception.

How can I implement cosine distance to use it only from code, I don't need all the functions related to GUI?

Comment: Can you show what you have already tried? Perhaps listing the problems with your current approach will be more useful?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that many algorithms in Weka are strongly depend on their distance functions, so that if you just change the distance function in an algorithm, it may causes an inconsistency. For example in k-means, if you change Euclidean to Cosine distance, the results don't make sense. Because k-means has been designed to minimize an objective function based on Euclidean distance. When k-means compute averaging in Cartesian Space , it is attempting to minimize summation of Euclidean distances. Right way for using cosine distance is changing some main steps of the algorithm. In case of k-means, we have spherical k-means that uses cosine. This is why Weka was not designed to enable you for injecting any implementation of distance interface in any algorithms.